# Transmission torrent client sequential download

Tags: bittorrent, transmission, torrent, transmission-daemon

I'm using TransmissionBT torrent client (http://www.transmissionbt.com/).

Is it possible to make simple modification in code to be able to download files in sequential mode (from beginning of the file). Then it will be possible to play video file without waiting to finish downloading whole file.
I found solution for it - https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Can%20I%20sequence%20the%20files%20I%20download but it's from 7 years ago and in current version there is no function mentioned in link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found working solution on github:
https://github.com/midenok/transmission-patches

Comment: Per author comments on the Issues page, it's not fully working code, last development was seven years ago.

Answer (score 8):

The qBittorrent has such a built-in function, from the context menu of the torrent

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I previously did it using Deluge with the Pieces plugin but Deluge is currently broken on Ubuntu 20.04 due to a Python error (C++ also has the advantage that it is compiled instead of interpreted like Python).

Answer (score 0):

The good news here: the sequential download feature is [implemented](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/pull/4795) and should be available in the pending 4.1.0 version of the Transmission.
Unstable [Nightly](https://transmissionbt.com/download) builds are available already.